# How to serialize this Xml in .NET (array)

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I need Xml that looks like this

```
<foo>
  <bar ... />
  <bar ... />
</foo>
```

And currently have the following class structure :

```
[XmlRoot("foo")]
public class Foo
{
  [XmlArrayItem("bar")]
  public List<Bar> myBars;
}
```

But this gives me Xml where bar items are wrapped inside a bars element. How should I define my custom XmlAttributes so I'd get the Xml structure I need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to solve something similar yesterday, and this was the solution for me:

```
[XmlRoot("foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement("bar")]
    public List<Bar> myBars;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution I use is this:

```
[XmlRoot("foo")]
public class Foo : List<Bar>
{
}

[XmlType("bar")]
public class Bar
{
}
```

In fact, I defined `Foo` as a `List<T>`, so it works as a generic list. The type in that list just needs to define the `XmlType` attribute.

Comment: Can have only one right answer :( I would've liked to mark both as correct answers.